# How to change procedure name in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, cdecl

When I compile DLL in C++ Builder with my procedure

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl void show_m(void)
{
 MessageBox(NULL, "MSG", "COTI DLL", MB_OK |MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

I can see in depends.exe that name of my procedure is _show_m.
How can I remove underscore? (rename procedure inside dll)

Thanx

Comment: it does depend on the linker (in this case Borland's (uh, Embaracado's)), but most probably it accepts a **module definition file**. by convention those files have filename extension ".def". google up some documentation and examples, and your problem is solved. remember to write up the solution here so others can benefit. tia. ;-)

Comment: I found how to create .DEF file, and I did it, but I do not know how to use it during DLL compilation or what to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found solution. In C++ Builder (Code Gear 2009) I set FALSE to:

Options->C++ Compiller->Output->Generate underscore on sympol names->FALSE

I think we can close topic.

Comment: You "close" a question on Stackoverflow by "accepting" an answer. Click the checkmark to the left of this answer. See [About] for more info.